# Override Biblatex style: missing pagination

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to use the `style=chem-angew` but override that @article has no page prefix. I couldn't find any working solution yet (without doing manual changes on the bibliography or changing the style itself) and seek for help.

This is my working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}                            
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Eder.1983.types}
\cite{Fattahi.2005}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

bib.bib

```
@book{Eder.1983.types,
 author = {Eder, Franz Xaver},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Arbeitsmethoden der Thermodynamik: Band II Thermische und kalorische Stoffeigenschaften},
 address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
 publisher = {{Springer Berlin Heidelberg}},
 pages = {125--261}
}

@article{Fattahi.2005,
 author = {Fattahi, Alireza and Kass, Steven R. and Liebman, Joel F. and Matos, M. Agostinha R. and Miranda, Margarida S. and Morais, Victor M. F.},
 year = {2005},
 title = {The enthalpies of formation of o-, m-, and p-benzoquinone: gas-phase ion energetics, combustion calorimetry, and quantum chemical computations combined},
 pages = {6116--6122},
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

The desired output has the prefix `p.~`/`pp.~` for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore [the original definition from `biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L550), which prints the page prefix, as follows

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}
```

Here the optional argument `article` applies this change only to `@article`s (since all other types have the prefix anyway). If you want to reset the format for all entry types, go with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}
```

In this case there is no difference between the two approaches (because `@article` was the only type with a definition different from the rest).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Eder.1983.types,
  author    = {Eder, Franz Xaver},
  year      = {1983},
  maintitle = {Arbeitsmethoden der Thermodynamik},
  volume    = {2},
  title     = {Thermische und kalorische Stoffeigenschaften},
  address   = {Berlin and Heidelberg},
  publisher = {Springer},
  pages     = {125--261}
}
@article{Fattahi.2005,
  author  = {Fattahi, Alireza and Kass, Steven R. and Liebman, Joel F.
             and Matos, M. Agostinha R. and Miranda, Margarida S.
             and Morais, Victor M. F.},
  year    = {2005},
  title   = {The Enthalpies of Formation of o-, m-, and p-Benzoquinone: 
             Gas-Phase Ion Energetics, Combustion Calorimetry,
             and Quantum Chemical Computations Combined},
  pages   = {6116--6122},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  volume  = {127},
  number  = {16},
  doi     = {10.1021/ja042612f},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Eder.1983.types}
\cite{Fattahi.2005}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: A. Fattahi, S. R. Kass, J. F. Liebman, M. A. R. Matos, M. S. Miranda, V. M. F. Morais, J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2005, 127, pp. 6116–6122.]